# Trying to pass texture from framebuffer results in L_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: Source and destination textures of the draw are the same

Tags: javascript, webgl, framebuffer

I'm new to vanilla WebGL and trying to utilize framebuffers for post processing/advanced shaders. When I run my code I get the warning:

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: Source and destination textures of the draw are the same.

Here's my code so far. If anyone could point me to the right direction how to correctly utilize framebuffers to pass textures to the next pass. It's wrapped in a vue.js component but that shouldn't matter.

```
<template lang='pug'>

    canvas

</template>

<script>

import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
    name: 'webGl',
    created ()
    {
        this.static = {
            af: null,
            gl: null,
            fr: 0,
            shaders:
            {
                vertex: `
                attribute vec2 a_position;

                void main() {
                    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0, 1);
                }`,
                fragment: `
                #ifdef GL_ES
                precision mediump float;
                #endif

                uniform float u_time;
                uniform vec2 u_size;
                uniform int u_frame;
                uniform sampler2D u_texture;

                const int maxIter = 15;

                vec2 getPos() {
                    vec2 pos = ( gl_FragCoord.xy / u_size.xy ) - vec2(0.5);
                    pos.x *= u_size.x / u_size.y;
                    return pos;
                }

                vec2 cmult(vec2 a, vec2 b){
                    return vec2(a.x*b.x-a.y*b.y,a.x*b.y+a.y*b.x);
                }

                float length2(vec2 v){
                    return v.x*v.x+v.y*v.y;
                }

                vec2 map(vec2 pos){
                    return pos;
                    return vec2(pos.x * sqrt(1.-pos.y*pos.y*3.), pos.y * sqrt(1.-pos.x*pos.x*2.));
                }

                vec2 iterate(vec2 p, vec2 c){
                    vec2 p2 = cmult(p,p);
                    return p2 + c;
                }

                bool checkAbort(vec2 p, vec2 c){
                    return length2(p) > 400.;
                }

                float l2 = log(2.);

                vec4 defaultColor ( void )
                {
                    return vec4(0.35,0.35,0.35,1.0);
                }

                vec4 color(int iterations, vec2 p){
                    float col = .20 + (float(iterations) - log(log(length2(p)))/l2) / float(maxIter);
                    return defaultColor() * vec4(col);
                }

                void main( void ){
                    if (u_frame < 300)
                    {
                        vec2 c = map(getPos())*0.8 - vec2(0.5);
                        vec2 p = c + vec2(sin(-u_time), cos(u_time)) * 0.2;
                        float m;

                        for(int i = 0; i < maxIter ;i++) {
                            p = iterate(p,c);
                            if(checkAbort(p,c)){
                                gl_FragColor = color(i,p);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        gl_FragColor = defaultColor();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, gl_FragCoord.xy / u_size.xy);
                    }
                }`,
                program: null,
                attributes: {},
                uniforms: {},
                time: 0
            }
        }
    },
    mounted ()
    {
        this.setInitWebGlContext()
        this.setInitShaderProgram()
        this.setInitAttributes(['a_position'])
        this.setInitUniforms(['u_size', 'u_time', 'u_frame', 'u_texture'])
        this.setInitGeometryBuffer()

        this.setRenderLoop()
    },
    beforeDestroy ()
    {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.static.af)
    },
    computed:
    {
        ...mapGetters([
            'getCalcs'
        ])
    },
    methods:
    {
        setInitWebGlContext ()
        {
            this.static.gl = this.$el.getContext('webgl')

            if (this.static.gl === null)
            {
                console.log('Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser or machine may not support it.')
            }
        },
        setInitShaderProgram ()
        {
            const gl = this.static.gl

            this.static.shaders.program = gl.createProgram()

            const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER)
            const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)

            gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, this.static.shaders.vertex)
            gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, this.static.shaders.fragment)

            gl.compileShader(vertexShader)
            gl.compileShader(fragmentShader)

            gl.attachShader(this.static.shaders.program, vertexShader)
            gl.attachShader(this.static.shaders.program, fragmentShader)
            gl.linkProgram(this.static.shaders.program)
            gl.useProgram(this.static.shaders.program)
        },
        setInitAttributes (keys)
        {
            const gl = this.static.gl
            const program = this.static.shaders.program

            for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
            {
                this.static.shaders.attributes[keys[i]] = gl.getAttribLocation(program, keys[i])
            }
        },
        setInitUniforms (keys)
        {
            const gl = this.static.gl
            const program = this.static.shaders.program

            for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
            {
                this.static.shaders.uniforms[keys[i]] = gl.getUniformLocation(program, keys[i])
            }
        },
        setInitGeometryBuffer ()
        {
            const gl = this.static.gl
            const buffer = gl.createBuffer()

            gl.bindBuffer(this.static.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
        },
        setCreateTexture ()
        {
            const gl = this.static.gl
            const width = this.getCalcs.vw
            const height = this.getCalcs.vh
            const texture = gl.createTexture()

            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture)
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null)

            return texture
        },
        setCreateFramebuffer ()
        {
            const gl = this.static.gl
            const buffer = gl.createFramebuffer()

            gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, buffer)

            const texture = this.setCreateTexture()

            gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0)

            return {
                texture: texture,
                buffer: buffer
            }
        },
        setRenderLoop ()
        {
            this.static.af = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.setRenderLoop)

            const gl = this.static.gl
            const fb = this.static.fb
            const width = this.getCalcs.vw
            const height = this.getCalcs.vh
            const attributes = this.static.shaders.attributes
            const uniforms = this.static.shaders.uniforms
            const mouse = this.static.shaders.mouse
            const fr = this.static.fr

            this.$el.width = width
            this.$el.height = height

            const bufferA = this.setCreateFramebuffer()

            gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height)
            gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attributes.a_position)
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(attributes.a_position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
            gl.uniform2f(uniforms.u_size, width, height)
            gl.uniform1f(uniforms.u_time, window.performance.now() / 3000)
            gl.uniform1i(uniforms.u_frame, fr)
            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6)

            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, bufferA.texture)
            gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null)

            gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height)
            gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attributes.a_position)
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(attributes.a_position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
            gl.uniform2f(uniforms.u_size, width, height)
            gl.uniform1f(uniforms.u_time, window.performance.now() / 3000)
            gl.uniform1i(uniforms.u_frame, fr)
            gl.uniform1i(uniforms.u_texture, 0)
            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6)

            this.static.fr++
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

I'm now some steps further this code below is now working

```
<template lang='pug'>

    canvas

</template>

<script>

import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

import forEach from 'lodash/forEach'

export default {
    name: 'webGl',
    created ()
    {
        this.static = {
            af: null,
            gl: null,
            fr: 0,
            shaders:
            {
                noise:
                {
                    vertex: `
                    attribute vec2 a_position;

                    void main() {
                        gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0, 1);
                    }`,
                    fragment: `
                    #ifdef GL_ES
                    precision mediump float;
                    #endif

                    uniform vec2 u_size;

                    vec2 hash( vec2 p ) {
                        p = vec2( dot(p,vec2(127.1,311.7)),
                        dot(p,vec2(269.5,183.3)));

                        return -1.0 + 2.0 * fract(sin(p) * 43758.5453123);
                    }

                    float noise( vec2 p ) {

                        const float K1 = 0.366025404;
                        const float K2 = 0.211324865;

                        vec2 i = floor(p + (p.x + p.y) * K1);
                        vec2 a = p - i + (i.x + i.y) * K2;
                        vec2 o = step(a.yx, a.xy);
                        vec2 b = a - o + K2;
                        vec2 c = a - 1.0 + 2.0 * K2;

                        vec3 h = max(0.5 - vec3(dot(a,a), dot(b,b), dot(c,c)), 0.0);

                        vec3 n = h * h * h * h * vec3(dot(a, hash(i + 0.0)), dot(b, hash(i + o)), dot(c, hash(i + 1.0)));

                        return dot(n, vec3(70.0));
                    }

                    void main( void ) {
                        vec2 vUv = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_size.xy;
                        vec3 rnd = vec3(noise(16.0 * vUv + 1.1), noise(16.0 * vUv + 2.2), noise(16.0 * vUv + 3.3));
                        gl_FragColor = vec4(rnd, 1.0);
                    }`,
                    program: null,
                    attributes:
                    {
                        a_position: null
                    },
                    uniforms:
                    {
                        u_size: null
                    }
                },
                fluid:
                {
                    vertex: `
                    attribute vec2 a_position;

                    void main() {
                        gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0, 1);
                    }`,
                    fragment: `
                    #ifdef GL_ES
                    precision mediump float;
                    #endif

                    uniform vec2 u_size;
                    uniform sampler2D u_image;

                    vec2 normz(vec2 x) {
                        return x == vec2(0.0, 0.0) ? vec2(0.0, 0.0) : normalize(x);
                    }

                    vec3 advect(vec2 ab, vec2 vUv, vec2 step, float sc) {

                        vec2 aUv = vUv - ab * sc * step;

                        const float _G0 = 0.25; // center weight
                        const float _G1 = 0.125; // edge-neighbors
                        const float _G2 = 0.0625; // vertex-neighbors

                        // 3x3 neighborhood coordinates
                        float step_x = step.x;
                        float step_y = step.y;
                        vec2 n  = vec2(0.0, step_y);
                        vec2 ne = vec2(step_x, step_y);
                        vec2 e  = vec2(step_x, 0.0);
                        vec2 se = vec2(step_x, -step_y);
                        vec2 s  = vec2(0.0, -step_y);
                        vec2 sw = vec2(-step_x, -step_y);
                        vec2 w  = vec2(-step_x, 0.0);
                        vec2 nw = vec2(-step_x, step_y);

                        vec3 uv =    texture2D(u_image, fract(aUv)).xyz;
                        vec3 uv_n =  texture2D(u_image, fract(aUv+n)).xyz;
                        vec3 uv_e =  texture2D(u_image, fract(aUv+e)).xyz;
                        vec3 uv_s =  texture2D(u_image, fract(aUv+s)).xyz;
                        vec3 uv_w =  texture2D(u_image, fract(aUv+w)).xyz;
                        vec3 uv_nw = texture2D(u_image, fract(aUv+nw)).xyz;
                        vec3 uv_sw = texture2D(u_image, fract(aUv+sw)).xyz;
                        vec3 uv_ne = texture2D(u_image, fract(aUv+ne)).xyz;
                        vec3 uv_se = texture2D(u_image, fract(aUv+se)).xyz;

                        return _G0*uv + _G1*(uv_n + uv_e + uv_w + uv_s) + _G2*(uv_nw + uv_sw + uv_ne + uv_se);
                    }

                    void main( void ) {

                        const float _K0 = -20.0/6.0; // center weight
                        const float _K1 = 4.0/6.0;   // edge-neighbors
                        const float _K2 = 1.0/6.0;   // vertex-neighbors
                        const float cs = -0.6;  // curl scale
                        const float ls = 0.05;  // laplacian scale
                        const float ps = -0.8;  // laplacian of divergence scale
                        const float ds = -0.05; // divergence scale
                        const float dp = -0.04; // divergence update scale
                        const float pl = 0.3;   // divergence smoothing
                        const float ad = 6.0;   // advection distance scale
                        const float pwr = 1.0;  // power when deriving rotation angle from curl
                        const float amp = 1.0;  // self-amplification
                        const float upd = 0.8;  // update smoothing
                        const float sq2 = 0.6;  // diagonal weight

                        vec2 vUv = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_size.xy;
                        vec2 texel = 1. / u_size.xy;

                        float step_x = texel.x;
                        float step_y = texel.y;
                        vec2 n  = vec2(0.0, step_y);
                        vec2 ne = vec2(step_x, step_y);
                        vec2 e  = vec2(step_x, 0.0);
                        vec2 se = vec2(step_x, -step_y);
                        vec2 s  = vec2(0.0, -step_y);
                        vec2 sw = vec2(-step_x, -step_y);
                        vec2 w  = vec2(-step_x, 0.0);
                        vec2 nw = vec2(-step_x, step_y);

                        vec3 uv =    texture2D(u_image, fract(vUv)).xyz;
                        vec3 uv_n =  texture2D(u_image, fract(vUv+n)).xyz;
                        vec3 uv_e =  texture2D(u_image, fract(vUv+e)).xyz;
                        vec3 uv_s =  texture2D(u_image, fract(vUv+s)).xyz;
                        vec3 uv_w =  texture2D(u_image, fract(vUv+w)).xyz;
                        vec3 uv_nw = texture2D(u_image, fract(vUv+nw)).xyz;
                        vec3 uv_sw = texture2D(u_image, fract(vUv+sw)).xyz;
                        vec3 uv_ne = texture2D(u_image, fract(vUv+ne)).xyz;
                        vec3 uv_se = texture2D(u_image, fract(vUv+se)).xyz;

                        vec3 lapl  = _K0*uv + _K1*(uv_n + uv_e + uv_w + uv_s) + _K2*(uv_nw + uv_sw + uv_ne + uv_se);
                        float sp = ps * lapl.z;

                        float curl = uv_n.x - uv_s.x - uv_e.y + uv_w.y + sq2 * (uv_nw.x + uv_nw.y + uv_ne.x - uv_ne.y + uv_sw.y - uv_sw.x - uv_se.y - uv_se.x);

                        float sc = cs * sign(curl) * pow(abs(curl), pwr);

                        float div  = uv_s.y - uv_n.y - uv_e.x + uv_w.x + sq2 * (uv_nw.x - uv_nw.y - uv_ne.x - uv_ne.y + uv_sw.x + uv_sw.y + uv_se.y - uv_se.x);
                        float sd = uv.z + dp * div + pl * lapl.z;

                        vec2 norm = normz(uv.xy);

                        vec3 ab = advect(vec2(uv.x, uv.y), vUv, texel, ad);

                        float ta = amp * ab.x + ls * lapl.x + norm.x * sp + uv.x * ds * sd;
                        float tb = amp * ab.y + ls * lapl.y + norm.y * sp + uv.y * ds * sd;

                        float a = ta * cos(sc) - tb * sin(sc);
                        float b = ta * sin(sc) + tb * cos(sc);

                        vec3 abd = upd * uv + (1.0 - upd) * vec3(a,b,sd);

                        abd.z = clamp(abd.z, -1.0, 1.0);
                        abd.xy = clamp(length(abd.xy) > 1.0 ? normz(abd.xy) : abd.xy, -1.0, 1.0);
                        gl_FragColor = vec4(abd, 0.0);
                    }`,
                    program: null,
                    attributes:
                    {
                        a_position: null
                    },
                    uniforms:
                    {
                        u_size: null
                    }
                },
                colorize:
                {
                    vertex: `
                    attribute vec2 a_position;

                    void main() {
                        gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0, 1);
                    }`,
                    fragment: `
                    #ifdef GL_ES
                    precision mediump float;
                    #endif

                    uniform vec2 u_size;
                    uniform sampler2D u_image;

                    void main( void ) {
                        vec2 texel = 1. / u_size.xy;
                        vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_size.xy;
                        vec3 c = texture2D(u_image, uv).xyz;
                        vec3 norm = normalize(c);

                        vec3 div = vec3(0.1) * norm.z;
                        vec3 rbcol = 0.5 + 0.6 * cross(norm.xyz, vec3(0.5, -0.4, 0.5));

                        gl_FragColor = vec4(rbcol + div, 1.0);
                    }`,
                    program: null,
                    attributes:
                    {
                        a_position: null
                    },
                    uniforms: {
                        u_size: null
                    }
                }
            },
            textures:
            {
                default: null
            }
        }
    },
    mounted ()
    {
        this.setInitWebGlContext()
        this.setInitGeometryBuffer()
        this.setInitShaderPrograms()
        this.setRenderLoop()
    },
    beforeDestroy ()
    {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.static.af)
    },
    computed:
    {
        ...mapGetters([
            'getCalcs'
        ])
    },
    methods:
    {
        setInitWebGlContext ()
        {
            this.static.gl = this.$el.getContext('webgl')

            if (this.static.gl === null)
            {
                console.log('Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser or machine may not support it.')
            }
        },
        setInitShaderPrograms ()
        {
            const gl = this.static.gl

            forEach(this.static.shaders, shader =>
            {
                shader.program = gl.createProgram()

                const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER)
                const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)

                gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, shader.vertex)
                gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, shader.fragment)

                gl.compileShader(vertexShader)
                gl.compileShader(fragmentShader)

                gl.attachShader(shader.program, vertexShader)
                gl.attachShader(shader.program, fragmentShader)

                gl.linkProgram(shader.program)
            })
        },
        setInitGeometryBuffer ()
        {
            const gl = this.static.gl
            const buffer = gl.createBuffer()

            gl.bindBuffer(this.static.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
        },
        setDraw (width, height)
        {
            const gl = this.static.gl

            gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
            gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height)
            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6)
        },
        setProgram (shader)
        {
            const gl = this.static.gl
            const program = this.static.shaders[shader].program
            const attributes = this.static.shaders[shader].attributes
            const uniforms = this.static.shaders[shader].uniforms

            gl.useProgram(program)

            forEach(attributes, (attribute, key) =>
            {
                attributes[key] = gl.getAttribLocation(program, key)
            })

            forEach(uniforms, (uniform, key) =>
            {
                uniforms[key] = gl.getUniformLocation(program, key)
            })
        },
        setFrameBuffer (width, height)
        {
            const gl = this.static.gl
            const texture = gl.createTexture()

            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture)
            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null)
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR)
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE)

            const framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer()

            gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer)
            gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0)

            return {
                frameBuffer: framebuffer,
                texture: texture
            }
        },
        setNoise (width, height)
        {
            const gl = this.static.gl
            const attributes = this.static.shaders.noise.attributes
            const uniforms = this.static.shaders.noise.uniforms

            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attributes.a_position)
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(attributes.a_position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
            gl.uniform2f(uniforms.u_size, width, height)
        },
        setFluid (width, height)
        {
            const gl = this.static.gl
            const attributes = this.static.shaders.fluid.attributes
            const uniforms = this.static.shaders.fluid.uniforms

            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attributes.a_position)
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(attributes.a_position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
            gl.uniform2f(uniforms.u_size, width, height)
        },
        setColorize (width, height)
        {
            const gl = this.static.gl
            const attributes = this.static.shaders.colorize.attributes
            const uniforms = this.static.shaders.colorize.uniforms

            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attributes.a_position)
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(attributes.a_position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
            gl.uniform2f(uniforms.u_size, width, height)
        },
        setRenderLoop ()
        {
            this.static.af = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.setRenderLoop)

            const gl = this.static.gl
            const width = this.getCalcs.vw
            const height = this.getCalcs.vh

            this.$el.width = width
            this.$el.height = height

            if (!this.static.fr)
            {
                const noiseBuffer = this.setFrameBuffer(width, height)

                this.setProgram('noise')
                this.setNoise(width, height)
                this.setDraw(width, height)

                this.static.textures.default = noiseBuffer.texture
            }

            const fluidBuffer = this.setFrameBuffer(width, height)

            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.static.textures.default)

            this.setProgram('fluid')
            this.setFluid(width, height)
            this.setDraw(width, height)

            this.static.textures.default = fluidBuffer.texture

            gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null)

            this.setProgram('colorize')
            this.setColorize(width, height)
            this.setDraw(width, height)

            this.static.fr++
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

However i'm trying to adopt a shader from shadertoy https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XddSRX and if i rum my code it's behaving very differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is exactly as stated in the error.

> Source and destination textures of the draw are the same.

Looking at your code there is one shader, it references a texture, there is one texture, it's attached to the framebuffer AND it's bound to texture unit 0 the default. So, when you draw it's being used as both an input (`u_texture`) and as the output (the current framebuffer). That's not allowed.

The simple solution is you need another texture. Bind that texture when drawing to the framebuffer.

The better solution is you need 2 different shader programs. One for when drawing to the framebuffer that uses no texture as input and another for drawing to the canvas . As it is you have one shader that branches on `u_frame`. Remove that branch and separate things into 2 shader programs. The one that computes colors then u_frame < 300 and the one that use a texture. Use the computing one to draw to the framebuffer and the texture one to draw the framebuffer's texture to the canvas.

A few links that may or may not be helpful: [drawing multiple things](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html), [render targets](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html), [image processing](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing-continued.html).